# Drawing circle in webgl looks like ellipse

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm new to webgl and trying to draw circle but somehow it looks like an ellipse not exact shape that I want. Where did I made mistake (or other problem in code)?

index.html files just contains canvas element with width=900 height=600. So I didn't add it here.

```
var vertexShader=['precision mediump float;','attribute vec2 vPosition;','attribute vec3 vColor;','varying vec3 fragColor;','void main()','{','fragColor=vColor;','gl_Position=vec4(vPosition,0.0,1.0);','}'].join('\n');
var fragmentShader=['precision mediump float;','varying vec3 fragColor;','void main(){','gl_FragColor=vec4(fragColor,1.0);','}'].join('\n');


function init(){
console.log('running');
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var gl=canvas.getContext('webgl');

//CLEAR
gl.clearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);//R,G,B,Alfa
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);//gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT

//SHADERS
var vertShader=gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(vertShader,vertexShader);
var fragShader=gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(fragShader,fragmentShader);
gl.compileShader(vertShader);
gl.compileShader(fragShader);

//PROGRAM
var program=gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program,vertShader);
gl.attachShader(program,fragShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

var numberofsides=360;
var triangleVertices=yuvarlakCiz(-0.19,0,0,0.35,numberofsides);
var triangleVertices2=yuvarlakCiz(-0.1,0,0,0.29,numberofsides); 
triangleVertices=renkAyarla(1.0,1.0,1.0,triangleVertices);
triangleVertices2=renkAyarla(1.0,0.0,0.0,triangleVertices2);
console.log(triangleVertices);
//BUFFER
var triangleBuffer=gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,triangleBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(triangleVertices),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
//LOCATION ALMA
var attloc=gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vPosition');
var attcolor=gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vColor');
//ATTRIBUTE AYARLAMA
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    attloc,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    attcolor,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    2*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
);
//İLK CIRCLE ÇİZME
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attloc); 
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attcolor);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,numberofsides+2);  
//2.CIRCLE BUFFER
var circle2=gl.createBuffer(); 
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,circle2);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(triangleVertices2),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var attloc1=gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vPosition');
var attcolor1=gl.getAttribLocation(program,'vColor');
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    attloc1,
    2,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    0
);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    attcolor1,
    3,
    gl.FLOAT,
    gl.FALSE,
    5*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,
    2*Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT
);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attloc1);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(attcolor1);
//gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,numberofsides+2);


}

function yuvarlakCiz(x,y,z,radius,numberofsides){
var numberofVertices=numberofsides+2;
var doublepi=2*Math.PI;

var verticesX=[];
var verticesY=[];
var verticesZ=[];
verticesX[0]=x;
verticesY[0]=y;
verticesZ[0]=z;
for (var i = 1 ;i<numberofVertices; i++) {
 verticesX[i]=x+(radius * Math.cos(i*doublepi/numberofsides));      
 verticesY[i]=y+(radius * Math.sin(i*doublepi/numberofsides));
 verticesZ[i]=z;
}
var mergeVertices=[];
for (var i = 0 ;i<numberofVertices; i++) {
 mergeVertices[i*5]=verticesX[i];
 mergeVertices[i*5+1]=verticesY[i];
 mergeVertices[i*5+2]=0.0;
 mergeVertices[i*5+3]=0.0;
 mergeVertices[i*5+4]=0.0;
// mergeVertices[i*3+2]=verticesZ[i];
}
return mergeVertices;
}

function renkAyarla(r,g,b,dizi){ //SETTING COLORS
for (var i =0; i <dizi.length/5; i++) {
    dizi[i*5+2]=r;
    dizi[i*5+3]=g;
    dizi[i*5+4]=b;
}
return dizi;
}
```

[Circle Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlwJK.png)

Comment: You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's missing is compensating for the fact that your viewport is not a square. If you were to make it a square by doing something like this:

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, 600, 600);
```

you would get the correct circles.

To support any viewport size, you have to use something like a projection transformation. You could look up [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). You would basically multiply all your coordinates with something like this:

```
 ( 600 / gl.drawingBufferWidth, 600 / gl.drawingBufferHeight )
```

Comment: I've been looking for almost 1 hour and was thinking i was missing something in formula or something.And its about width and height not same problem :) Thank you for answer

Answer (score 3):

What's missing is that WebGL always takes clip space coordinates that go from -1 to +1 across the canvas regardless of dimensions so if your canvas is not square you need to find some math to compensate.

Since it's just math there are 1000 ways to change the code.

One would be multiplying your position by the aspect of the canvas.

You currently have this

```
gl_Position=vec4(vPosition,0.0,1.0);
```

You could change it to this

```
gl_Position=vec4(vPosition * vec2(600.0/900.0, 1),0.0,1.0);
```

You could change it to make it so you can pass in scale

```
uniform vec2 scale;
...
gl_Position=vec4(vPosition * scale,0.0,1.0);
```

Then set `scale` to `600.0 / 900.0, 1` by looking up its location and setting it

A more common way is to use one or more matrices

```
uniform mat4 matrix;
...
gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
```

In which case you can apply the same scale as a above but you can also do tons of other things.

[This series of articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) covers all of these solutions and more